# How to run a single xunit C# test using dotnet test command line

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, command-line, xunit

**Background:** I am trying to run a C# unit test (**test is using Xunit Framework**), and my requirement is to ***run a single unit test and not all*** the tests in the whole dll.

**Things I tried:** I have tried few commands, but with no luck till now.

1. I tried `dotnet test "complete_path/someTestDll.dll"`
   Result : This starts running all the test in the dll (expected but not desired)
2. Tried `dotnet test "complete_path/someTestDll.dll" \Tests: "Namespace.ClassName.MethodToRun"`
   Result: Dll containing the test found but no test matches the filter.
3. Tried `dotnet test "complete_path/someTestDll.dll" --filter "FullyQualifiedName=Namespace.ClassName.MethodToRun"`
   No test matching filter is found (again path to dll is alright)
4. Tried `dotnet test "complete_path/someTestDll.dll" --filter "DisplayName=Namespace.ClassName.MethodToRun"`

Not only these but various mix and match of these with complete path, relative path, etc. etc. and almost wasted whole day.

**NOTE:** *I know there are few answers on this over SO, but I have tried them all, from last day, and nothing seems to be working for me till now, so I had to come here to get some help.*

Looks like I am missing something serious, Hopefully, I can get some answers which solves my issue.

Thanks a lot!!

[image]

Comment: Is it an option for you to just add `[Fact(Skip = "Your reason to not run the test")]` the skip parameter to your tests?  I guess this wouldn't be ideal if you intend to run some of them later.

Comment: @JonathanVanDam
Thanks for your answer, but this option is not feasible for me, as I have 4k unit tests in the dll in different classes and it is impractical to be adding this on each test.
I just want a way to run a single unit test with providing its name for local testing purpose.
Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, the only other thing I can think of is using playlists inside of visual studio to create a set of unit tests that are to be run, but I'm unaware of a way to run the tests from the playlists from the command line.

Comment: okay, I am also not sure about that. Also, my whole intent to use command line is that I don't want to use Visual Studio as that is terribly slow.
Thanks!

Comment: I was able to get the `FullyQualifiedName=Namespace.ClassName.MethodToRun` to work.  The only reason it didn't work was if I didn't have the fully qualified name put in correctly or the method wasn't a test.  I wonder if there's something wrong with the fully qualified name.

Comment: Okay, here is something I have found out, that this command (as suggested by Stev here) is working for other tests, and not with just this test, though I am still not sure what is wrong with this. Need to check. and I guess the one you tried will work too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to run a single xunit test via the developer command prompt using this template.

```
dotnet test "complete_path/someTestDll.dll" --filter "Namespace.ClassName.MethodName"
```

You can also run this command to see a full list of tests available, to help double check that the paths and names in your command are correct.

```
dotnet test "complete_path/someTestDll.dll" -t
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I tried this too and is not working.
doing dotnet test  "dllHere" -t lists all the tests, but again using the filter I get no tests found. Updated the question with image for the same.

Comment: Okay, here is something I have found out, that this command is working for other tests, and not with just this test, though I am still not sure what is wrong with this. Need to check. I will update here with the findings. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

1. Run inside the solution.

   dotnet test [project folder name] --filter=Namespace.ClassName.MethodName
2. Run inside the project.

   cd [project folder name]

   dotnet test --filter=Namespace.ClassName.MethodName

Answer (score 0):

with xUnit, you can simply run the following command to run scenarios with specific tags

```
dotnet test "(path to the test dll file)" --filter Category=scenarioTag
```

You can create conditions for the filters as long as you put them inside of a string.

```
dotnet test "(path to the test dll file)" --filter "Category=scenarioTag|Category=scenarioTag2"
```